# Scraping SVG tags from website using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape SVG tags from a website. The issue is when I manually copy the SVG tag and save it (for example `image.svg`) it perfect., but when scraping and save as `.svg` file the image is broken and error.

here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

image_url = 'https://www.hudl.com/'
request = Request(image_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
client = urlRequest(request)
# time.sleep(1)
data = client.read()

time.sleep(2)
# image
data_soup = soup(data, 'html.parser')
image_ = data_soup.find('div', {'class': 'mobile-toggle'})
image_ = image_.find('svg')
```

Comment: can you provide full code and website url?

Comment: this is website https://www.hudl.com/ it requires login

Comment: didn't find any class named `drawing-area` in the page content. Are you targetting the correct class name?

Comment: sorry, this is the correct url to page https://www.hudl.com/playtools/playbook/manage/27073/offense/play/5dc8dcfc51abdf10fc751098  however it requires login, you can replace class name with this for home page "mobile-toggle", thanks

Comment: Oh, can you provide one short reprodicble sample then?

Comment: image_url = 'https://www.hudl.com/'
    driver.get(image_url)

    time.sleep(2)

    # image
    html_ = driver.page_source
    data_soup = soup(html_, 'html.parser')
    image_ = data_soup.find('div', {'class': 'mobile-toggle'})
    image_ = image_.find('svg')

Comment: this is a code for home page

Comment: Working fine at my side.

Comment: it grab csv tag, the issue is when i convert the output to .csv it not form an image.

Comment: you mean .svg not .csv?

Comment: yes sorry, you are right .svg

Comment: can you check the code, it is working my side

Comment: yes sir, code running perfectly, the issue is in the output it not forming .svg image. when i save it as image.svg the open image has an error. the code getting wrong format of SVG. if i copy <svg></svg> tag from website manually and save as image.svg it showing same image on website but using scrapper it not giving same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
url = 'https://www.hudl.com/en_gb/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
image_ = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'mobile-toggle'})
image_ = image_.find('svg')
image_ = [i.find('svg') for i in image_]

for index, i in enumerate(image_):
    with open(f'image_{index}.svg', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(i))
```

Comment: thanks, this code run perfectly the issue is if i open the image_0.svg its broken image.

Comment: that is strange, it is working fine at my side

Comment: i will check downloading a new image viewer. thanks for the help

Comment: you can use google chrome to view it. Right click and open with chrome or internet explorer